-fa 'Cascadia Code' → "xterm: no absolute path found for shell"
I have recently installed Cascadia Code (because I love its "4") and I can use it in XTerm
$ xrdb -merge
XTerm*faceName: Cascadia Code
^D
$ 

but, otoh, if I try using the command line
$ xterm -fa 'Cascadia Code'
$ xterm: No absolute path found for shell: Code

(above, the error message is printed after the prompt!).
I know the Unix SE Q&A xterm no absolute path found for shell, and I can understand the error message except that XTerm shouldn't look at Code in isolation.
What I'm missing?

As a follow up to a now deleted comment (ty Chris Davies) I tried xterm -fa 'Cascadia\ Code', xterm -fa 'Cascadia\\ Code', xterm -fa 'Cascadia\\\ Code', xterm -fa 'Cascadia\\\\ Code' to finally realize that any number of backslashes, it doesn't matter.

I'm on Suse Tumbleweed,
$ xterm -v
$ XTerm(389)

(also here the message is printed after the next prompt).
Here it is the output of fc-list:
$ fc-list 'Cascadia Code'
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-Italic.otf: Cascadia Code:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-SemiBoldItalic.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-LightItalic.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-SemiBold.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-SemiLight.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code SemiLight:style=SemiLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-Light.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-ExtraLight.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-ExtraLightItalic.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-Bold.otf: Cascadia Code:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-BoldItalic.otf: Cascadia Code:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-Regular.otf: Cascadia Code:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-cascadia-code/CascadiaCode-SemiLightItalic.otf: Cascadia Code,Cascadia Code SemiLight:style=SemiLight Italic,Italic
$ 


perhaps you have a shell alias, which is causing another layer of interpretation

@ThomasDickey Oh my! you're right (as usual…) /usr/bin/xterm -fa 'Cascadia Code' works perfectly.  Thank you!
